# Find element with jquery and assign css class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find a div with a certain css class and assign to body a class

```
if ($('div').class(home)) {
    $("body").addClass("mobile-bg");
}
```

But its not working

Comment: Why did you use `.class()`, when, for example, Google suggests a lot of links with `.hasClass()` description on _jquery check element has class_ request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use .hasClass() not class()

```
if ($('div').hasClass('home')) {
    $("body").addClass("mobile-bg");
}
```

this code mean .. if div has  class="home" add  class="mobile-bg" to body

Answer (score 0):

Or as an alternative to Mohamed's solution,

```
if ($('div.home').length > 0) {
    $("body").addClass("mobile-bg");
}
```

This checks if there are any `<div>` elements with the class `home`, and if *any* exist, it adds the `mobile-bg` class to the `<body>`.